# Running 2 JavaFx projects?

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I have written a client-server application and I made the client GUI in JavaFX. To test the functionality of my application, I am trying to run 2 instances of Eclipse with the same project in each Eclipse workspace ( I have two workspaces : one contains the client and the server, the other one contains the same client project ). When I hit run on both client projects, the GUI freezes and I have no alternative but to close them.

Does anyone know a solution for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't really need two instances of Eclipse to do this: just run the server and the client project twice from a single Eclipse instance. But there's no a priori reason it should lock up either way; it means you have some problem with your code. See if you can create a *minimal* complete example which behaves this way (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: If I run the client project twice, it opens the first stage. And only after I am changing the scene in the first stage, the stage from the second instance appears. It is odd

Comment: Also, I don't understand why one is blocking the other? Aren't they independent instances?

Comment: Well, yes, but that's why your question can't be answered without seeing an example. Presumably they are both communicating with the same server, and the communication is somehow creating deadlock.

Comment: Thank you James, indeed, the problem was caused by deadlock. Your above answer is correct, starting two instances of the client project is done as you told.